# Passenger Standalone for Meteor behind a custom Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, meteor, passenger

I have created a Meteor app which runs at http://localhost:3000. I am using the following Nginx server directive:

```
server {  
  listen 80;

  server_name example.com;
  charset utf-8;

  location ~ /(.+) {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

The `location ~ /(.+)` allows me to place a simple file at `public/index.html` which will be served to anyone who requests `http://example.com/` directly. All other requests, such as `http://example.com/whatever` will be handled by the Meteor app, and served with the Meteor sauce.

I can get this to work in production when I use node to launch the app:

```
export ROOT_URL=http://localhost && export PORT=3000 && node main.js
```

However, all my attempts to get this to work with Phusion Passenger have failed. I've been following the instructions for [Putting Passenger Standalone behind an Nginx or Apache reverse proxy](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/standalone/reverse_proxy.html), but despite all my juggling with Passenger and Nginx configurations, I can either see only the contents of the `public/` folder or the Meteor app, but not both.

Here's what my `Passengerfile.json` currently looks like, in case that helps.

```
{
  "app_type": "node",
  "startup_file": "main.js",
  "envvars": {
    "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://localhost:27017/example",
    "ROOT_URL": "http://example.com",
  },
  "log_file": "../passenger.log",
  "pid_file": "../passenger.pid",
  "environment": "production",
  "port": 3000,
  "daemonize": true,
  "user": "meteor"
}
```

Does my Nginx directive conflict with the way Passenger works under the hood?